# How to convert the result of a query to the original dataset in scala sql?

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe, dataset

I have a case class :

`case class User(date: String, type: String, car: String, house String, income: BigDecimal)`

I am running a query to return aggregated data like:

```
def user(data : Dataset[User]): Dataset[User] = {
    user.groupBy("date", "car", "house")
        .sum("income")
        .select("date", "car", "house", "sum(income)")
        .withColumNameRenamed("sum(income)", "income")
}
```

I want to convert the result back to case class Dataset[User] and return all aggregated data